# Achievement order in default game center view controller

Tags: ios, gamekit, achievements

Is there a way to control the order achievements are shown in the Game Center achievement view controller (GKAchievementViewController)? Currently they are showing up in the order I created them in iTunes Connect.

I did see that it is also possible to import all the achievement info for use in a custom achievement viewer where I could set the order myself, but I would prefer to just use the already existing viewer if possible.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Finally got an answer that works, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-order the achievements in iTunes Connect.  Does that help?

Comment: You're right! There is a draggy area on the left side of each achievement in iTunes connect. I never noticed this, thanks so much.